# sql questions meeting and matching all the records

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a SQL query on finding if two people went to the same place on the same days.

For example, if John went to Walmart on 15/03/2018, 10/02/2018, and 03/01/2018 and if Doe went to Walmart on those same days the show the results.

But if Doe went to Walmart on 15/03/2018, 10/02/2018, and not 03/01/2018, then don't show this record.

Here is the schema of the table.
`visitation (username, name, place, date);`

```
john, John, Walmart, '15/03/2018'
john, John, Walmart, '10/02/2018'
john, John, Walmart, '03/01/2018'

doe, Doe, Walmart, '15/03/2018'
doe, Doe, Walmart, '10/02/2018'
doe, Doe, BestBuy, '11/13/2018'
```

The output for the above should be zero.

I know I'll have to self join on the place and day and username not equal username2, but how would I check if the 2nd person went to the same place on the same days and the other person?

Any help would be great.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

First, your should maybe look into using association tables. It seems you have a lot of duplicate data in your table that could easily lead to confusion (if you insert "Jonh" instead of "John" it would already not recognize it as the same person!).

So you should have a table for `users` and a table for `places` and an extra association table where you connect them both:

```
visitations(user_id, place_id, date)
```

Therefore, by using foreign key constraints you can easily query the relationships and get the join you need.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work, if you knew the two users that you wanted to compare, in advance.

```
   SELECT * FROM visitation AS v1 
      JOIN visitation v2 ON v1.place = v2.place 
                  AND v1.visitdate = v2.visitdate 
  WHERE v1.username='john' AND v2.username = 'joe';
```

This effectively is an intersect, which MySQL doesn't support.

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/162be0a/6)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you would do the simple aggregation and then filter the records

```
SELECT * FROM visitation 
 WHERE place NOT IN (
      SELECT place
      FROM visitation
      GROUP BY place, visitdate
      HAVING COUNT(distinct username) = 1))
```